# How to serialize custom arraylist object and save it to sqlite database?

Tags: android, sqlite, parsing, serialization, arraylist

I want to save custom arraylist object in sqlite database when i search about it on internet i got to know that i need to make my class **serialize**. But problem is that my that class is **Parcelable** and i,m sending values from one activity to another with the help of **Parcelable**.

**Medicine.class**

```
public class Medicine implements Parcelable {

// Private Variables

int _id;
String _product_Code;
String _product_name;
String _type;
int _price;
int _quantity;

//empty constructor
public Medicine(){

}

//constructor
public Medicine(int id, String product_code,String product_name, String type, int price, int quantity){
    this._id = id;
    this._product_Code = product_code;
    this._product_name = product_name;
    this._type = type;
    this._price = price;
    this._quantity = quantity;
}

public Medicine(String product_code,String product_name, String type, int price, int quantity){
    this._product_Code = product_code;
    this._product_name = product_name;
    this._type = type;
    this._price = price;
    this._quantity = quantity;
}

public String get_product_Code() {
    return _product_Code;
}

public void set_product_Code(String _product_Code) {
    this._product_Code = _product_Code;
}

public Medicine(Parcel p){
    set_id(p.readInt());
    set_product_name(p.readString());
    set_type(p.readString());
    set_price(p.readInt());
    set_quantity(p.readInt());
}

public int get_id() {
    return _id;
}

public void set_id(int _id) {
    this._id = _id;
}

public String get_product_name() {
    return _product_name;
}

public void set_product_name(String _product_name) {
    this._product_name = _product_name;
}

public String get_type() {
    return _type;
}

public void set_type(String _type) {
    this._type = _type;
}

public int get_price() {
    return _price;
}

public void set_price(int _price) {
    this._price = _price;
}

public int get_quantity() {
    return _quantity;
}

public void set_quantity(int _quantity) {
    this._quantity = _quantity;
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    dest.writeInt(get_id());
    dest.writeString(get_product_name());
    dest.writeString(get_type());
    dest.writeInt(get_price());
    dest.writeInt(get_quantity());
}

public static final Parcelable.Creator<Medicine> CREATOR  = new Creator<Medicine>() {

    public Medicine createFromParcel(Parcel source) {

        return new Medicine(source);
    }

    public Medicine[] newArray(int size) {

        return new Medicine[size];
    }

};
```

}

In this class **ShowMedicineList** i,m saving the values in arraylist named as **"nextValuesOf"** and passing to next activity **SelectedMedicineList**

```
    Button btnAddMedicine = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonAddSelectedMed);
    btnAddMedicine.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Intent intent = new Intent(ShowMedicineList.this, SelectedMedicineList.class);
            //intent.putExtra("ccode", o._product_name);
            //intent.putExtra("cname", o._quantity);
            //intent.putExtra("caddress", amount);
            intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("myArrayL", nextValuesOf);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
```

Here is the onCreate Method of **SelectedMedicineList class** where i,m receiving the intent. Now i want to this **selectedProducts** arraylist in my database. Please advice me the solution or code for it

```
public ArrayList<Medicine> selectedProducts = new ArrayList<Medicine>();

DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.selected_medicine_info);

     selectedProducts = getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("myArrayL");
     LinkedHashSet<Medicine> hs = new LinkedHashSet<Medicine>();
     hs.addAll(selectedProducts);
     selectedProducts.clear();
     selectedProducts.addAll(hs);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) library to save and retrieve the data in any of your data structure. The Idea is that the library converts(serialize and deserialize) your object to/from `JSON`  format

So create a database column with the field type as `TEXT` and convert your arraylist to JSON object as

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String arrayList = gson.toJson(yourArraylist);
```

and save this string into database.

and while retrieving take a string from database and convert into your original list as

```
Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<YourClass>>() {
                    }.getType();
 List<YourClass> yourClassList = new Gson().fromJson(jsonArray, listType);
```

Hope this one helps

Comment: I tried your this method but i,m getting error its not saving it in string format